# Is there a way to make Netbeans file uploads not fail on a single error?

Tags: netbeans, ftp, netbeans-6.9

Is there a way to make Netbeans's FTP uploads less error sensitive(reconnect and retry on error)?

It is simply unable to handle large amounts of files. If I upload 1000 files and there is some sort of failure at the 400th file, it will fail for the rest of the files, and it will not record the files that failed. So I will have to upload ALL the files again, even the ones that uploaded successfully on the previous attempt, but it will fail agan again and again.

Answer (score 1):

This [post](https://superuser.com/questions/154198/netbeans-remote-synchronization-failed-to-save-file) describes changing a NetBeans FTP setting to Passive. Doing so reduced many of my transfer errors.